# Angular2 single parameter routing not working

Tags: angular, typescript, parameter-passing

my simple routing is not working and I don't know why...
The command below reported load the **PageNotFoundComponent** instead of **OffertDetailComponent**

## app.routing

```
{
    path: "OffertDetail/:idOffert",
    component: OffertDetailComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

## route command

```
this.router.navigate(['OffertDetail', {idOffert: 1073}]);
```

If i remove the "/idOffert" from ap.Routing and the parameter from the command, the component loads properly.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are mixing query params and route params.  Try changing your `router.navigate` to the following while keeping the path as `"OffertDetail/:idOffert"`:

```
this.router.navigate(['OffertDetail', '1073']);
```

From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

To set query params:

```
// Set our navigation extras object
// that contains our global query params and fragment
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: { 'session_id': sessionId },
  fragment: 'anchor'
};

// Navigate to the login page with extras
this.router.navigate(['/login'], navigationExtras);
```

To use route params:

```
this.router.navigate(['/hero', hero.id]);
```

And the parameter gets the name of the `:param` from the router config.

To pass two route parameters  Say our path in our route config is `path: "OffertDetail/:idOffert/detail/:someId"`, we could pass parameters to that like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/OffertDetail', someParameter, 'detail', someOtherValue]);
```

Comment: thanks, this work. Just to complete, can you provide me a simple code that shows how to pass 2 parameters instead of 1 ?